# Remove text before first occurrence of a substring

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to delete the other texts before the first `<tr class="vcard agent">` in a document.

Note: There are multiple `<tr class="vcard agent">` s in the document.

Comment: Give us an example of what the html looks like

Comment: Also, use a more descriptive title.

Comment: @Zeta Two: I edited the title but it's not up until it's reviewed.

Comment: Also, dont use regex, use the PHP DOMDocument class

Comment: Any solution that doesn't use an actual HTML parser is going to be fragile, because some day that page's content is going to change to be `<tr id="foo" class="vcard agent">` and then your code is broken.  http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html gives more examples of why regexes are not the way to manipulate HTML.

Answer (score 5):

```
$answer = strstr($oriString,'<tr class="vcard agent">');
```

See [`strstr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might work:

```
preg_replace('/.*?<tr class="vcard agent">/', '<tr class="vcard agent">', $string);
```

Edit: [Pradeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174907/php-remove-text-before-first-tr/7174992#7174992) looks like it is the best one.

Comment: That's great until the page actually contains `<tr id="foo" class="vcard agent">` and then the code stops working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = strpos($html, '<tr class="vcard agent">');
$result = substr($html, $first);
```