# What's Wrong With This Code

Tags: php

```
<?php

$html = 'sdfknjasdf kjfdasj fjknadssajkndf kjadsknajsdfjndfasjk <tr class="vcard agent">
<span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Brad_Jones_(footballer)" title="Brad Jones (footballer)">Brad Jones</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Glen_Johnson_(English_footballer)" title="Glen Johnson (English footballer)">Glen Johnson</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Enrique_S%C3%A1nchez" title="José Enrique Sánchez">José Enrique</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Raul_Meireles" title="Raul Meireles">Raul Meireles</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Daniel_Agger" title="Daniel Agger">Daniel Agger</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/F%C3%A1bio_Aur%C3%A9lio" title="Fábio Aurélio">Fábio Aurélio</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Luis_Su%C3%A1rez_(Uruguyan_footballer)" title="Luis Suárez (Uruguyan footballer)" class="mw-redirect">Luis Suárez</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Steven_Gerrard" title="Steven Gerrard">Steven Gerrard</a></span> <i>(<a href="/wiki/Captain_(association_football)" title="Captain (association football)">captain</a>)</i></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Andy_Carroll" title="Andy Carroll">Andy Carroll</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Joe_Cole" title="Joe Cole">Joe Cole</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Maxi_Rodr%C3%ADguez" title="Maxi Rodríguez">Maxi Rodríguez</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Daniel_Pacheco" title="Daniel Pacheco">Daniel Pacheco</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jordan_Henderson" title="Jordan Henderson">Jordan Henderson</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Alberto_Aquilani" title="Alberto Aquilani">Alberto Aquilani</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Dirk_Kuyt" title="Dirk Kuyt">Dirk Kuyt</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Stewart_Downing" title="Stewart Downing">Stewart Downing</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jay_Spearing" title="Jay Spearing">Jay Spearing</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Lucas_Leiva" title="Lucas Leiva">Lucas Leiva</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Danny_Wilson_(Scottish_footballer)" title="Danny Wilson (Scottish footballer)">Danny Wilson</a></span></td>
</tr>

</table>

</td>

<td width="1%"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" width="48%">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">

<tr bgcolor="#AAD0FF">
<th width="1%">No.</th>

<th width="1%"></th>
<th width="1%">Position</th>
<th width="75%">Player</th>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jamie_Carragher" title="Jamie Carragher">Jamie Carragher</a></span> <i>(<a href="/wiki/Captain_(association_football)#Vice-captain" title="Captain (association football)">vice-captain</a>)</i></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/David_N%27Gog" title="David N'Gog">David N'Gog</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Manuel_Reina" title="José Manuel Reina">Pepe Reina</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Charlie_Adam" title="Charlie Adam">Charlie Adam</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Christian_Poulsen" title="Christian Poulsen">Christian Poulsen</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn">Jesús Fernández Sáez (Suso)</span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Raheem_Sterling" title="Raheem Sterling">Raheem Sterling</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Doni%C3%A9ber_Alexander_Marangon" title="Doniéber Alexander Marangon">Doni</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jonjo_Shelvey" title="Jonjo Shelvey">Jonjo Shelvey</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Martin_Kelly" title="Martin Kelly">Martin Kelly</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Conor_Coady" title="Conor Coady">Conor Coady</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Martin_%C5%A0krtel" title="Martin Škrtel">Martin Škrtel</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/John_Flanagan_(English_footballer)" title="John Flanagan (English footballer)">John Flanagan</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Nathan_Eccleston" title="Nathan Eccleston">Nathan Eccleston</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn">Andre Wisdom</span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jack_Robinson_(footballer_born_1993)" title="Jack Robinson (footballer born 1993)">Jack Robinson</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/David_Amoo" title="David Amoo">David Amoo</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Philipp_Degen" title="Philipp Degen">Philipp Degen</a></span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="vcard agent">
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Emiliano_Ins%C3%BAa" title="Emiliano Insúa">Emiliano Insúa</a></span></td>
</tr>

</table>';

$first = strpos($html, '<tr class="vcard agent">');
$result = substr($html, $first);

echo $result;

?>
```

I want to delete the

> sdfknjasdf kjfdasj fjknadssajkndf kjadsknajsdfjndfasjk

before the first occurrence of `<tr class="vcard agent">`

Comment: Your example seems incomplete. I also assume not all the vcard entries are necessary, so it would make the question easier to read if you only left in one or two as long as that demonstrates the problem. Finally, I would suggest clearly stating your current and expected output. These things make it much easier for people to help :)

Comment: What does it do or not do what expected?

Comment: Did the error message not lead you to the line that's causing the problem?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: remove text before first <tr ...>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174907/php-remove-text-before-first-tr)

Answer (score 3):

For large spans of text, containign quotes use [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$html = <<<EOT
sdfknjasdf kjfdasj fjknadssajkndf kjadsknajsdfjndfasjk <tr class="vcard agent">
<span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Brad_Jones_(footballer)" title="Brad Jones (footballer)">Brad Jones</a></span></td>
</tr>
EOT;
```

Comment: True, but does it solve the actual problem?

Comment: Is there any other problem than the string being unescaped?

Comment: I don't know, do you? The question is a but unclear in the first place. It does not say what is going wrong.

Comment: I checked the rest of the code, and as long as `$text` contains correct data, the `$result` is `$text` less anything before first `<tr`. I also am not sure if that's what OP asked for, but it seems like that.

Comment: Okay...that was what I meaned by asking my question in the previous comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Escape all your single quotes with backslashes.

Example:

```
$html = '[...] <a href="/wiki/David_N%27Gog" title="David N'Gog">David N'Gog</a> [...]';
```

is incorrect, whereas

```
$html = '[...] <a href="/wiki/David_N%27Gog" title="David N\'Gog">David N\'Gog</a> [...]';
```

is correct.

Comment: I don't see a reason for the downvote. Is this not correct?

Comment: Though I wouldn't normally have upvoted this, I can't see a reason why you recieve a downvote so +1 to compensate.

Comment: Please comment on the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Find...

```
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/David_N%27Gog" title="David N'Gog">David N'Gog</a></span></td>
```

Replace with...

```
<td><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/David_N%27Gog" title="David N\'Gog">David N\'Gog</a></span></td>
```

Your code contains unescaped single quotes in two places.